# Creating Svelte component which I can import from node_modules later

Tags: webpack, svelte, svelte-component

I'm learning Svelte right now, and I have one thing that I cannot understand.

I can create a component with just a file with .svelte extension, and loader will make all the rest (for example, 'svelte-loader' for webpack).

But what if I want to create a component which I (and anyone) can import in future? If I will put .svelte file in node_modules/mycomponent, webpack will crash if I will not make some tweaks on it's config file (I mean removing line "exclude: /node_modules/")".

Is there any way to write a component in a way which not requires svelte-loader?

Thanks.

Comment: You can have multiple builds of your library. E.g. [this library has a UMD and ES build and also supplies the original `.svelte` file](https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-spinner/blob/master/rollup.config.js). These files are then [pointed to in `package.json`](https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-spinner/blob/db0a2439e19a0f967b82715aa5cd1bc9a62149c9/package.json#L5-L7). If you have a Svelte app though, it might be the best option to just change the `exclude` to `/node_modules\/(?!my-svelte-library)/`.

Comment: @Tholle thank you for detailed answer! However, I'm wondering if someone who uses Svelte app webpack template will install my extension (for example via NPM install), is it necessary for he or her to edit webpack config? And if it is so, can I do something for using my extension just out-of-the-box?

And more thank you for the example, I will try it later.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at existing packages. For instance [Svelte-Autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-autocomplete). If you take a look at the [package.json](https://github.com/elcobvg/svelte-autocomplete/blob/master/package.json) file you can see the following fields:

```
"svelte": "src/index.html",
"module": "dist/index.mjs",
"main": "dist/index.js"
```

The svelte one will be used for in your svelte project.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to build a component, but when I'm creating it like this: 
`let comp = new Component({
      target: document.querySelector('#special-id'),
      props: {
        test: "Test prop value"
      }
    });`
I get error: Uncaught Error: 'target' is a required option. I can't understand the problem because I give target as option...

Comment: It would be much easier to answer if you could share some of the code?